# What's a good data grid to use for django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

What's a good data grid to use for django?

Comment: Every data grid that fits your needs. Client-side things has nothing to do with Django.

Comment: If you want a data grid which supports nested grids, foreign key in-place editing, works as replacement for ForeignKeyRawIdWidget, try django-jinja-knockout. It works with django templates as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not DJANGO specific, but I'd take a loot at [JQGRID](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at django-tables2. Works great!

Comment: Very good application ! I recommend using it with [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) simply add the css and `Meta: attrs: {'class': 'table'}` to your Table class.